# Javascript native .remove() does not work on HTMLCollection. Javascript Bug?

Tags: javascript, htmlcollection

I'm simply trying to iterate through an HTMLCollection (images inside a div) with a simple for loop. I use the `children()` method to get the images, and the `item()` method to get the specific image. Although the console shows me each image element (that I am logging), using `remove()` on each element isn't working. It does not remove all images.

I've tried using array indexes, `removeChild()` method, but it's the same problem: so I guess the problem lies on the HTMLCollection capacity?

```
var imgs = document.getElementByID('box').children;
    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        var e = imgs.item(i);
        console.log(e)
        document.getElementByID('box').removeChild(e)
    }
}
```

HTML markup:

```
<div id="box">
    <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

I expect that every element will be removed from #box, but the second image element stays in place. I don't really grasp why.

Comment: You're using `.removeChild()` not `.remove()`

Comment: it's getElementById not getElementByID you will get "Uncaught TypeError"

Answer (score 1):

`HTMLCollection` is not an array, it is a live list of DOM elements. Therefore your loop goes like this:

1st round:

```
imgs = 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg
removeChild(imgs[0]) removes 1.jpg
```

2nd round:

```
imgs = 2.jpg, 3.jpg
removeChild(imgs[1]) removes 3.jpg
```

3rd round:

```
imgs = 2.jpg
removeChild(imgs[2]) removes undefined, does nothing
```

The simple fix is to loop through the array in reverse:

```
for (var i = imgs.length-1; i >= 0; i--) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would loop through all `childNodes` of the `div[id="box"]` and remove them accordingly.

Check out the code sample:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#box img')
  .forEach(node => {
    // do some additional checks, if needed
    node.remove();
  });
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please flag it as answer?

Answer (score 0):

The first problem you have is `document.getElementByID` - the correct method is [`.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) - lowercase `d` in the end.

Second, your loop will *miss* some elements. If you do a `for` loop and start removing elements, then the *length* of the collection also changes. What happens (in pseudo representation):

```
loop start

index = 0;
collection = [1, 2, 3];
remove item 0;

index = 1;
collection = [2, 3];
remove item 1;

index = 2;
collection = [2];
remove item 3; //error
```

You can loop *in reverse* from the end to the beginning but it's easier to use `forEach` which guarantees you go over each element in the initial array:

```js
document.getElementById("remove").addEventListener("click", removeImages)

function removeImages() {
  var imgs = document.getElementById('box').children;
  
  [...imgs].forEach(img => img.remove());
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="">
</div>

<button id="remove">Remove all</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `removeChild()`, not `remove()`.
A solution to your problem would be this:

```
let imgs = document.getElementById('box').children();
imgs.forEach(img => img.remove());
```